# Cannot install jupyter on windows

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I've been trying to install jupyter on my notebook. I just installed python 3.7 and when I try to install it using pip this happens [image](https://i.ibb.co/VNtkkL1/jupyterbug.png).

```
b/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721cOacOecfedb80e0d88c64:
9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5b'
e/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
```

It gets stuck there forever, I haven't seen this problem anywhere.
What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the internet?

Comment: @dodekja Yes, this problem is happening right now as I'm posting this, it's just stuck in that line, so weird

Comment: Try clicking inside the console and pressing any key.

Comment: @wjandrea When I type any key nothing happens

Comment: @Luciano Whoops, press Enter instead of just any key

Comment: @wjandrea Nothing. I typed Ctrl+C and it said operation cancelled by the user. Now I tried installing again using pip install jupyter and it justs stop again at collecting webencodings

Comment: Are you doing this from Powershell instead of the Command Prompt?

Comment: Is your pip up to date?

Comment: @HS-nebula yes, should I try the command prompt?

Comment: Pip is up to date

Comment: Which version of pip do you use? Can you try: `pip install webencodings` only. Or try `pip install "webencodings<0.5.1"` try another Wheel.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE using pip install webencodings, it says Collecting webencodings and freezes there.. I don't get it haha                                                       Same with webencodings<0.5.1

Comment: @LucianoPereira, the other libraries are cached, but webencodings is not. It seems that you have a pb with your Internet connection… This can be a problem with Windows firewall.

Comment: @LucianoPereira, if you have wget for Windows, you can try to download the file directly with the URL: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/24/2a3e3df732393fed8b3ebf2ec078f05546de641fe1b667ee316ec1dcf3b7/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Ok that seemed to work! now it's installing normally

Comment: @LucianoPereira. How do you solve that?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE  It worked, Thanks a lot!                                                              I downloaded the file you linked, then installed it, then when I did pip install jupyter, it just installed it without problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install jupyter notebook in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636998/install-jupyter-notebook-in-windows)